# How often should CVMetalTextureCache be flushed?

Tags: objective-c, macos, metal, core-video

I'm using `CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` to create metal textures from `CVPixelBuffers`. In `CVMetalTextureCache.h`, there is a method called `CVMetalTextureCacheFlush` that has the following comment attached to it:

> CVMetalTextureCacheFlush:
>
> - Performs internal housekeeping/recycling operations
> - This call must be made periodically to give the texture 
>               cache a chance to do internal housekeeping operations.

Roughly speaking, how frequently is "periodically" implying? Do I have to call flush after every 'n' calls to `CreateTextureFromImage`? Is it every other call? Every 10 calls? Every 100 calls? Or is it time based like every second or so?

I assume the texture cache has some resource limitations and needs to reclaim resources or old textures from time-to-time, but it's unclear to me how frequently `flush` needs to get called within an application.

Comment: I've seen apps before where this function is never called and it works fine, so I would be discretionary with its usage. This would be a good question to ask on the Apple Developer Forums, maybe a Metal engineer could chime in.